# Configure multiple websites in IIS 10 for https

Tags: ssl, iis

I want to configure 3 websites in IIS 10, all with https bindings only, using 3 separate domains and SSL certificates. I know I have to configure the https binding for each site on a different port, but is there a way to do this so the port does not have to be specified when accessing the website, and so it works on restricted networks that only allow port 443 traffic?

```
https://www.mywebsite1.com default 
https://www.mywebsite2.com instead of https://www.mywebsite2.com:444
https://www.mywebsite3.com instead of https://www.mywebsite2.com:445
```

Comment: IIS 10 supports SNI, so you don't need to use different port numbers.

Comment: Does this require multiple IP address , is it possible on aws ec2 instance?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same port number, but you must enable the option called "Requier Server Name Indication" in the Binding of your website and enter the hostname :

[image: IIS-SNI]